# Using HTML tags inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, explode

**Background**

I have a playlog.csv file sitting on various Raspberry PI, and has the following format:

```
2018-03-22 12:43:21,NM_Test.h264,-2 //PI 1
2018-03-22 12:43:21,NM_Test.h264,-2 //PI 2
2018-03-22 12:43:21,vid.h264,0 //PI 3
```

I can connect to each PI and tail the CSV file by:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
#circleRed {
    background: #ff0000;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#circleGreen {
    background: #00ff00;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
</style>

<?php
    require_once 'Net/SSH2.php';
    require_once 'phpseclib1.0.10/Crypt/RSA.php';
    $config = require 'config.php';
    $log = 'logfile.txt';

    if(is_array($config)){
        foreach($config as $cred){
            $ssh = new Net_SSH2($cred['ip'], $cred['port']); //get the IP and port 
            $key = new Crypt_RSA();
            $key->loadKey($cred['key']);

            if (!$ssh->login('pi', $key)){
                //logging with file_put_contants, Append mode, exclusive lock is more race condition safe then an open file handle.
                file_put_contents($log, "[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."]Login Failed for {$cred['ip']}\n", FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
                continue;
            }

            $output = $ssh->exec('tail -1 /var/log/playlog.csv');    
        }
    };

    $array = explode(',',$output);

    if(in_array('0', $array, true)){
        echo '<div id="circleGreen"></div>';
    }
    if (in_array('-2'||'-3'||'-4'||'-5', $array, true)){
        echo '<div id="circleRed"></div>';
    }
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**The Problem**

Looking at the right most value, if the value is '-2' or '-3' etc, I'd like a red circle to be displayed, but if the value is '0', I'd like to show a green circle on my webpage. I'm trying to do this for all the PIs that I have connected via SSH.

But currently when I run my code I get a blank webpage and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you checked that `$array` has content in it after `explode ()`?

Comment: `in_array('-2'||'-3'||'-4'||'-5', $array, true)` this makes no sense, the needle is set to "-2" because the value is truthy

Comment: Hi @wayneOS , no I hadn't. But I just did an echo on `$array` and I got `Array to string conversion` PHP notice. I will look into this as maybe this is why my code is failing?

Comment: use `print_r()`

Comment: `I get a blank webpage`, turn on error reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be carefull with strict-mode of `in_array()` because it is type-sensitive. For your case you can just check if the last element is less then zero or not. Here is an example. Although do everything in your foreach-loop to check every pi's return value.

```
foreach (...) {

    ...
    $output = $ssh -> exec ('tail -1 /var/log/playlog.csv');
    $array = explode (',', $output);

    if (end ($array) >= 0) {
        echo '<div id="circleGreen"></div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div id="circleRed"></div>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is such a simpler way for what I am trying to achieve! But your code will only work for the first returned output. So currently my `$output` will return `2018-04-18 12:55:29,nmmoney_2.h264,-2 2018-04-19 10:26:29,eurochange.h264,0` but the if statement only looks at `2018-04-18 12:55:29,nmmoney_2.h264,-2` and prints the red circle. It should read the next output `2018-04-19 10:26:29,eurochange.h264,0` and print a green circle?

Comment: then you need to put your output into the foreach-loop. I will unpdate my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
in_array('-2'||'-3'||'-4'||'-5', $array, true)
```

isn't doing what you think. `in_array` can only accept one value for the `$needle` parameter - this line will evaluate the initial expression to boolean true, and then check if `$array` contains that exact value.

If you want to check if there's any overlap between two array (i.e. if the values -2, -3, -4 or -5 exist anywhere within the exploded line), you can use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), e.g.

```
if (count(array_intersect(['-2', '-3', '-4', '-5'], $array))) {
  ...
```

Comment: or instead of using all the various functions that you can use, just use `explode`, and get the last element in the exploded string and just simply use a comparison `if ( last exploded element == 0)` or `if ( el == < 0)`, and thats it